# How to solve duplicate mySQL entry?

Tags: mysql

I'm pulling stats down from an external source but the external source has changed how it handles things which is causing me problems, everything else works but for 1 section of the database which is giving me duplicate entries, as nothing is being pulled the database enters the value of 0 so the next field would also have a value of 0, I tried auto increment but I still end up with a duplicate entry.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.11.1deb2+deb7u6
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Oct 27, 2016 at 02:44 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.52
-- PHP Version: 5.6.26-1~dotdeb+zts+7.1

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `forum`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `xf_yfl_rival_stats`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xf_yfl_rival_stats` (
  `match_id` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
  `player_ea_id` bigint(60) NOT NULL,
  `persona_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `club_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `assists` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `cleansheetsany` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `cleansheetsdef` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `cleansheetsgk` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `goals` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `goalsconceded` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `mom` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `passattempts` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `passesmade` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `pos` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `rating` double(4,2) NOT NULL,
  `redcards` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `saves` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `shots` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `tackleattempts` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `tacklesmade` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `yellowcards` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`player_ea_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `match_id` (`match_id`,`player_ea_id`),
  KEY `club_id` (`club_id`),
  KEY `player_ea_id` (`player_ea_id`),
  KEY `match_id_2` (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

I'm getting the duplicate entry for the field player_ea_id is there any possible way to bypass this?

My understanding of mySQL isn't the greatest, for example I pull down the match_id or persona_name and both of these fields have the same entry for the players however the player_ea_id is supposed to be unique, how do I get around this?

Comment: As an aside, I don't think the '3' in 'INT(3)' does whatever you think it does. Also, DOUBLE for rating seems odd. And bigint for club !?!? How many teams are there?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where you're using AUTO_INCREMENT.  But that is indeed what you need if you are not getting that column from your source.

Change the `player_ea_id` line of your table creation to this.

```
`player_ea_id` bigint(60) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Comment: Query without auto increment:
Server Error

Mysqli statement execute error : Duplicate entry '454644422-0' for key 'match_id'

Query with auto increment:
Server Error

Mysqli statement execute error : Duplicate entry '454644422-4' for key 'match_id'

I realise it says match_id but its not related to that field its the player_ea_id field thats causing the issues.

Comment: Are you sure it is giving you the duplicate error on that column?  You also have UNIQUE KEY for `match_id`.  That could be problem instead.

Comment: I tried to take the unqiue key off last night and the problem still persists.

This is the database after having added auto increment and bigint 60

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/B07G

Comment: Valyrean you're the man, I fixed it, the unique key was the issue which I did honestly remove last night but I must have missed something, it was 6am though.

Comment: Glad i could help. Please upvote or mark as answer where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

@Strawberry, every other part of that database works, its collects stats from the EA sports title FIFA 17, and the 4.2 is related to the players overall match rating which works fine.

@TheValyreanGroup I already tried auto increment it still ends up giving me a duplicate error although not on 0 but on 6 for example or 10, or 15 just whenever it decides to break down.  I can run a query and show you what it does on auto increment compared to how it is now if you like?